# Advanced Data Manipulation in R?

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to take a column of data (D) and turn each value into a new column title. Then I need to put the corresponding 'E' value into the new column. For example:

```
 A    B      C        D     E
Elm  1.1    Tree    AB10_A  1
Oak  1.2    Tree    AB10_A  1
Yew  1.3    Tree    AB10_B  2
Maple1.4    Tree    AB10_B  1
Ash  1.5    Tree    AB10_B  1
Elm  1.6    Tree    AB10_C  1
Maple1.7    Tree    AB10_C  1
Ash  1.8    Tree    AB10_D  3
Oak  1.9    Tree    AB10_E  3
```

Becomes:

```
A    B   C  AB10_A  AB10_B  AB10_C  AB10_D  AB10_E
Elm 1.1 Tree    1               
Oak 1.2 Tree    1               
Yew 1.3 Tree          2         
Maple1.4 Tree         1         
Ash 1.5 Tree          1         
Elm 1.6 Tree                  1     
Maple1.7 Tree                 1     
Ash 1.8 Tree                          3 
Oak 1.9 Tree                                   3
```

My dataset is very large and there are over 2000 unique D values. Any suggestions are welcome! Sorry my tables are so bad...

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
# your data
mydf <- 
read.table(text=' A    B      C        D     E
Elm  1.1    Tree    AB10_A  1
Oak  1.2    Tree    AB10_A  1
Yew  1.3    Tree    AB10_B  2
Maple 1.4    Tree    AB10_B  1
Ash  1.5    Tree    AB10_B  1
Elm  1.6    Tree    AB10_C  1
Maple 1.7    Tree    AB10_C  1
Ash  1.8    Tree    AB10_D  3
Oak  1.9    Tree    AB10_E  3', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cbind(mydf, model.matrix(~0+D, data=mydf)*mydf$E)

      A   B    C      D E DAB10_A DAB10_B DAB10_C DAB10_D DAB10_E
1   Elm 1.1 Tree AB10_A 1       1       0       0       0       0
2   Oak 1.2 Tree AB10_A 1       1       0       0       0       0
3   Yew 1.3 Tree AB10_B 2       0       2       0       0       0
4 Maple 1.4 Tree AB10_B 1       0       1       0       0       0
5   Ash 1.5 Tree AB10_B 1       0       1       0       0       0
6   Elm 1.6 Tree AB10_C 1       0       0       1       0       0
7 Maple 1.7 Tree AB10_C 1       0       0       1       0       0
8   Ash 1.8 Tree AB10_D 3       0       0       0       3       0
9   Oak 1.9 Tree AB10_E 3       0       0       0       0       3
```

Basically, `model.matrix` generates indicator variables corresponding to unique values of a vector (or multiple vectors) and then you just vector multiply that matrix by your `E` column to move the relevant values of `E` into those new dummy columns. You could obviously rename those variables so they are preceded by "D", but I figure that's both easy and not that big a deal.

To get a sense of what's going on here, take a look just at the output of the `model.matrix` part before we multiply and `cbind`:

```
> model.matrix(~0+D, data=mydf)
  DAB10_A DAB10_B DAB10_C DAB10_D DAB10_E
1       1       0       0       0       0
2       1       0       0       0       0
3       0       1       0       0       0
4       0       1       0       0       0
5       0       1       0       0       0
6       0       0       1       0       0
7       0       0       1       0       0
8       0       0       0       1       0
9       0       0       0       0       1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$D
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

You see indicators. The key part of this is expressing the model as a formula object. In this case transforming `D` into indicators. If you don't have the `0+` part, one level of `D` would be treated as baseline as in a regression model:

```
> model.matrix(~D, data=mydf)
  (Intercept) DAB10_B DAB10_C DAB10_D DAB10_E
1           1       0       0       0       0
2           1       0       0       0       0
3           1       1       0       0       0
4           1       1       0       0       0
5           1       1       0       0       0
6           1       0       1       0       0
7           1       0       1       0       0
8           1       0       0       1       0
9           1       0       0       0       1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$D
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

And some benchmarking compared to Ananda's solution:

```
> microbenchmark(ananda(bigDf), thomas(bigDf))
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
  tfun(bigDf) 250.7615 286.2535 302.1688 347.5075 405.7631   100
 myFun(bigDf) 225.1035 231.1711 248.7156 270.0286 349.7964   100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `reshape`:

```
reshape(df, v.names="E", direction="wide", timevar="D", idvar=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

which produces:

```
      A   B    C E.AB10_A E.AB10_B E.AB10_C E.AB10_D E.AB10_E
1   Elm 1.1 Tree        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
2   Oak 1.2 Tree        1       NA       NA       NA       NA
3   Yew 1.3 Tree       NA        2       NA       NA       NA
4 Maple 1.4 Tree       NA        1       NA       NA       NA
5   Ash 1.5 Tree       NA        1       NA       NA       NA
6   Elm 1.6 Tree       NA       NA        1       NA       NA
7 Maple 1.7 Tree       NA       NA        1       NA       NA
8   Ash 1.8 Tree       NA       NA       NA        3       NA
9   Oak 1.9 Tree       NA       NA       NA       NA        3
```

Alternatively, with package `reshape2`:

```
dcast(df, A + B + C ~ D, value.var="E", fill="")
```

Rows are not in same order in result, but it's basically the same and simpler to express.

Comment: I always try base `reshape` first but can never get it to work. It is my bane

Comment: Nice. `reshape` for me seems to always involve just trying every variable in every function argument until it looks right. Always impressed by a solution using it.

Comment: @Thomas, LOL, that's exactly what I did.  I personally always use `dcast`, but appreciate the preference for base solutions when base solutions work (even if it means trying every possible argument permutation).

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this solution. I think that both the `reshape` and `dcast` solution would collapse the table unless the combination of columns A, B, and C create a unique ID.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, yes, this will collapse, but it is trivial to add an arbitrary unique `id` column to either approach, or if desired, a summarizing function to `dcast`.

Comment: @BrodieG, just making sure it is obvious. It's always unpleasant to think something has done what you expected only to find out you have a third fewer rows than you thought you should have!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, fair enough, though note in this case both `dcast` and `reshape` warn you about what they are doing should it turn out your reshape specification is non unique.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `reshape` just tells you that there were warnings and that you should use `warnings()` to view them all, and `dcast` tells you that it is defaulting to `length` as the aggregation functions. The first time I saw those warnings, I had no idea what they meant (though I at least like to think that I've now come a long way with my understanding of base R's `reshape`).

Comment: @rawr, so I stupidly decided to waste a whole bunch of time trying to figure out what the equivalent of a fairly simple `melt`/`cast` operation was in base.  **[Ridiculously painful and complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722565/how-to-reorganize-a-dataframe-in-r/22722753#22722753)**, though sharing it because I think it helps understand how you're supposed to use those arguments.

Comment: @Thomas, see above comment...  Need to thank Hadley personally for writing `reshape2`.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually also consider a manual approach like the following:

```
myFun <- function(indf, colvar = "D", valvar = "E", fill = 0) {

  ## Get the unique values in the "colvar" variable
  X <- unique(indf[, colvar])

  ## Create an empty matrix preallocated with whatever you
  ##   desire as the "fill" value
  M <- matrix(fill, ncol = length(X), nrow = nrow(indf), 
              dimnames = list(NULL, X))

  ## Use matrix indexing to *quickly* replace values in the
  ##   matrix with values from whichever column you specify
  M[cbind(sequence(nrow(indf)), match(indf[, colvar], X))] <- indf[, valvar]
  M
}
```

The function above just creates an empty matrix with the same number of columns as there are unique values in the column specified by "colvar" and fills in the relevant values in this matrix with the values from the column specified in "valvar".

```
cbind(mydf, myFun(mydf))
#       A   B    C      D E AB10_A AB10_B AB10_C AB10_D AB10_E
# 1   Elm 1.1 Tree AB10_A 1      1      0      0      0      0
# 2   Oak 1.2 Tree AB10_A 1      1      0      0      0      0
# 3   Yew 1.3 Tree AB10_B 2      0      2      0      0      0
# 4 Maple 1.4 Tree AB10_B 1      0      1      0      0      0
# 5   Ash 1.5 Tree AB10_B 1      0      1      0      0      0
# 6   Elm 1.6 Tree AB10_C 1      0      0      1      0      0
# 7 Maple 1.7 Tree AB10_C 1      0      0      1      0      0
# 8   Ash 1.8 Tree AB10_D 3      0      0      0      3      0
# 9   Oak 1.9 Tree AB10_E 3      0      0      0      0      3
```

---

The above function performs quite well on larger datasets too.

```
## 10K rows, 2K unique values in column "D"
set.seed(1)
bigDf <- data.frame(A = sample(LETTERS, 10000, TRUE),
                    B = sample(letters, 10000, TRUE),
                    C = "Tree",
                    D = sample(2000, 10000, TRUE),
                    E = sample(5, 10000, TRUE),
                    ID = 1:10000,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

system.time(myFun(bigDf))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.303   0.056   0.371
```