# How to reorganize a dataframe in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I import a CSV file into a `data.frame` using `read.table()`. The `data.frame` looks something like:

```
X1        X2   X3
Sample    A  
Lot      new
Name     Vol   %
Data     0.1   10
Data     0.2   20
Data     0.3   30
Sample    B  
Lot      old
Name     Vol   %
Data     0.1   50
Data     0.2   60
Data     0.3   70
```

I would like to reorganize this `data.frame` such that the first 3 data points are associated with Sample 'A' and Lot 'new', while the last three become associated with Sample 'B' and Lot 'old' instead. I'm trying to think of an elegant way to do this without resorting to the use of for-loop, or  having to manually carve out the `data.frame` row-by-row using subset command (i.e. `dataA = mydataframe[4:6]`,).

The `data.frame` that I want in the end might look something like:

```
A_new_Vol  A_new_%   B_old_Vol   B_old_%
  0.1        10         0.1        50
  0.2        20         0.2        60
  0.3        30         0.3        70
```

where  Sample, Lot, Vol, and % information are incorporated into the column names themselves.

Another possibility is to have the `data.frame` be something like:

```
Sample   Lot   Vol   %
  A      new   0.1   10
  A      new   0.2   20
  A      new   0.3   30
  B      old   0.1   50
  B      old   0.2   60
  B      old   0.3   70
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `df`:

```
df <- setNames(df[-1, ], c("type", "Vol", "%"))
df.lst <- split(df, cumsum(df[, 1] == "Sample"))
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(df.lst, function(x) cbind(Sample=x[1, 2], Lot=x[2, 2], x[-(1:3), -1]))
)
```

Produces (this is available as `dput` at the end):

```
     Sample Lot Vol  %
1.5       A new 0.1 10
1.6       A new 0.2 20
1.7       A new 0.3 30
2.11      B old 0.1 50
2.12      B old 0.2 60
2.13      B old 0.3 70
```

If you want your alternate format, here is an option with `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
df.new$id2 <- ave(1:nrow(df.new), df.new$Sample, df.new$Lot, FUN=seq_along)
dcast(
  melt(df.new, id.vars=c("Sample", "Lot", "id2")), 
  id2 ~ Sample + Lot + variable
)
```

Produces:

```
  id2 A_new_Vol A_new_% B_old_Vol B_old_%
1   1       0.1      10       0.1      50
2   2       0.2      20       0.2      60
3   3       0.3      30       0.3      70
```

Basically, you need to add an id column, melt down one more time so you're truly in "long" format, and then `dcast` to wide format.

Or if you want base R you can do the same with (contributed by Ananda):

```
df.new <- within(df.new, {
  ID <- ave(rep(1, nrow(df.new)), Sample, FUN = seq_along)
  Time <- paste(Sample, Lot, sep = "_")
})
reshape(df.new, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="Time", drop=c("Sample", "Lot"))
```

Leads to:

```
    ID Vol.A_new %.A_new Vol.B_old %.B_old
1.4  1       0.1      10       0.1      50
1.5  2       0.2      20       0.2      60
1.6  3       0.3      30       0.3      70
```

---

`df.new` starts off as:

```
structure(list(Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Lot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("new", "old"), class = "factor"), Vol = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), "%" = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 60L, 70L), id2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("Sample", "Lot", "Vol", "%", "id2"), row.names = c("1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "2.11", "2.12", "2.13"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Very nice use of `cumsum`.

Comment: Your base `reshape` solution can be more straightforward if you just made your `timevar` from pasting together "Sample" and "Lot" directly in "df.new" rather than creating your "df.mlt" object.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I'm not sure how since `variable` doesn't exist until after the "melt".  I added the `dput` of `df.new` to the answer.  Note I still subscribe to the "try-every-permutation-of-every-parameter-in-`reshape`-until-something-approaching-desired-output-emerges" school of though, so I'd be happy if you can show me how to do it.  I tried what you suggested but got something not quite right.

Comment: @BrodieG, I'm a fan of `reshape` since it's what I started with. As such, it doesn't seem too obscure to me. Perhaps the authors made a mistake by trying to have one function for both "wide" and "long" variants. Anyway, here's how I would have approached this: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=8yhSfBTL

Comment: @AnandaMahto, great, thanks.  My problem with `reshape` is mostly that I haven't truly sat down with it enough to figure out exactly how it works because I find `reshape2` so much more intuitive.

Comment: +1 for not harping too much on `reshape` :-) In all honesty, it is a function that is probably due for an upgrade. I get the feeling that it was written to solve a very specific set of problems (the fixed concept of a "time" variable comes to mind. With the "data.table" implementation of `dcast`, it is starting to seem like a very slow function these days.

Answer (score 0):

```
prev_sample_indices <- which(df[[1]] == 'Sample')
sample_indices <- c(prev_sample_indices[-1], nrow(df) + 1)

df <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(seq_along(sample_indices), function(index) {
  sample_index <- prev_sample_indices[index]
  label <- df[sample_index, 2] # A or B
  lot <- df[sample_index + 1, 2] # old or new
  data.frame(structure(lapply(2:3, function(i)
    df[seq(sample_index + 3, sample_indices[index] - 1), i]
  ), .Names = paste0(label, "_", lot, "_", c("Vol", "pct"))))                       
}))
```

## Example

```
 df <- data.frame(c("Sample", "Lot", "Name", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Sample", "Lot", "Name", "Data", "Data", "Data"), c("A", "new", "Vol", (1:3)/10, "B", "old", "Vol", (1:3)/10), c("", "", "%", (1:3)*10, "", "", "%", (5:7)*10))
 colnames(df) <- paste0("X", 1:3)
 # Run above code
 print(df)
 #   A_new_Vol A_new_pct B_old_Vol B_old_pct
 # 1       0.1        10       0.1        50
 # 2       0.2        20       0.2        60
 # 3       0.3        30       0.3        70
```

Note you cannot use `%` in column names of a data.frame. It gets converted to a `.`.